# How to prevent hasattr from retrieving the attribute value itself

Tags: python, getattr, hasattr

I have a class that implements virtual attributes using `__getattr__`. The attributes can be expensive, e.g. performing a query. Now, I am using a library which checks if my object has the attribute before actually getting it.

As a consequence, a query is executed two times instead of one. Of course it makes sense to actually execute `__getattr__` to really know if the attribute exists.

```
class C(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print "I was accessed"
        return 'ok'

c = C()
hasattr(c, 'hello')
```

Is there any way to prevent this?

If Python supported `__hasattr__` then I could simply check if the query exists, has opposed to actually run it.

I can create a cache, but it is heavy since a query might have parameters. Of course, the server might cache the queries itself and minimise the problem, but it is still heavy if queries return a lot of data.

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand the situation correct, you need to cache based on `name` only, so that could be just a dictionary. BTW, why do you want to make it look like an attribute?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the object doesn't support the query?

Comment: `hasattr` is not a light-weight test for an attribute; it calls `getattr` essentially like `try: getattr('name'); except AttributeError: return False; else: return True`.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do what you want, other than by monkey patching `hasattr`, which would not be recommended. If there is no way to avoid calling `hasattr`, I believe your only choices are caching the result or allowing the query to run twice.

Comment: @shashank, if the query is not available (by name), then it returns the exception for attribute not found.

Comment: @bereal: because queries are accessed has attributes of an object. Sorry, too long to explain it all properly here.

Answer (score 6):

Although initially I was not fond of the idea of monkey patching, being a "bad idea" in general, I came across a very neat solution from 1999!!

http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/14972/

```
def hasattr(o, a, orig_hasattr=hasattr):
    if orig_hasattr(o, "__hasattr__"):
        return o.__hasattr__(a)
    return orig_hasattr(o, a)

__builtins__.hasattr = hasattr
```

Essentially it creates support for `__hasattr__` in Python, which is what I thought originally would be the optimal solution.

Comment: **Monkey patching is awesome.** Rubyists have long embraced the ugly monkey. So should Pythonistas. Your augmentation of the stock `hasattr()` builtin to support `__hasattr__()` special methods is the perfect example of that. Thanks for rejuvenating this elegant hackery!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is generally probably a bad pattern, but you can always check an object's underlying `__dict__`.

```
In [1]: class A(object):
   ....:     @property
   ....:     def wha(self):
   ....:         print "was accessed"
   ....:

In [2]: A.__dict__
Out[2]:
<dictproxy {'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>,
'__doc__': None,
'__module__': '__main__',
'__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>,
'wha': <property at 0x10f6b11b0>}>

In [3]: a = A()

In [4]: "wha" in a.__class__.__dict__
Out[4]: True
```

Comment: I think OP is dealing with a third-party library that calls `hasattr`, so this would require forking the library.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, the class is fine, and I need to use __getattr__(). Plus what @bjudson said.